# MySQL LEFT JOIN with OR condition

Tags: mysql

I have a tables :

```
table_a.date
2018-05-13 17:30:22
2018-05-13 17:30:22
2018-05-13 17:30:22
```

and :

```
table_b.date
2018-05-13 17:30:22
2018-05-13 17:30:23
2018-05-13 17:30:23
```

I need to LEFT JOIN these tables with condition : `table_a.date` = `table_b.date`, or `table_a.date` = `table_b.date + 1 second`.

more or less like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.date = table_b.date OR table_a.date = table_b.date (+ 1 second)
```

but I have no idea how to use `OR` condition as requirement of `LEFT JOIN`. what is the right SQL for this?

Comment: This should do it as is, doesn't it work? What error if any do you get when you run it?

Comment: Can you please show the expected result? If you allow for a second tolerance you'll get 3 x 3 = 9 result rows for the sample data shown. Is this what you want? (The correct syntax is `table_b.date + interval 1 second` by the way.) And you want a left outer join, because there may be situations when you find no match in table_b, but still want to show the table_a record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DATE_ADD as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.date = table_b.date
OR table_a.date = date_add(table_b.date, interval 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to check seconds just make both date in same format and check (if diff is just for seconds), remove seconds
Use `DATE_FORMAT(date, format_mask)`

```
SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON DATE_FORMAT(table_a.date, "%M %d %Y %h %i") = (table_a.date, "%M %d %Y %h %i")
```